# How to include punctuation in sheet name without interfering with the range

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to include Colon Punctuation ":" in my sheet name, however the api recognition the ":" as range definition which causes problems.

I tried to skip the ":" like this : "/:" but it didn't work.

for example :

`2019-07-28 22:36 B2C2!A:V`

will not work, however if i replace that ":"

`2019-07-28 22#36 B2C2`

it works normally

When it doesn't work, you'll get a message saying that the range you've selected is wrong.

Comment: `:` can be used for the sheet name in the Spreadsheet. If my understanding for your question is correct, can I ask you about your script for replicating the issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Well i can rename it as i want, however when i use the range with ":" included in the sheet name like this : ```2019-07-28 22:36 B2C2!A:V``` it will mistake the range : A:V for 22:36, you see ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that you wanted to use `2019-07-28 22:36 B2C2!A:V` as the sheet name. But in your situation, I could understand that you want to use `A:V` as the range. In this case, the sheet name is required to be enclosed by the single quotes like `'2019-07-28 22:36 B2C2'!A:V`. The reference is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation). Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. It will resolve your issue.

Comment: Got it thank you a lot for your help Tanaike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the sheet name: `'2019-07-28 22:36 B2C2'!A:V` . This is what you must do when working within the actual Sheets application as well, when the sheet name contains non-alphanumeric characters.